# Crash deploying Spring-Boot WAR in Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I managed to run a spring-boot web application with `java -jar` command. But when changing the packaging field into war (in pom.xml) and build it into war, it failed to run in tomcat 7.

I make my pom.xml's parent into:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.5.0.M7</version>
</parent>
```

and also:

```
public class ApplicationWebXml extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(
            SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

}
```

The error I got is:

```
INFO: Deploying web application archive /home/ichsan/coding/java/tools/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/webapps/hello.war
Jan 4, 2014 10:18:50 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/home/ichsan/coding/java/tools/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/webapps/hello/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Jan 4, 2014 10:18:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig getServletContainerInitializer
SEVERE: The ServletContentInitializer [org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci] could not be created
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1713)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
```

My questions are:

1. What happens here and how to overcome this?
2. Is it really safe to use spring-boot? Because the embedded server libraries seem affecting reliability of its deployment into j2ee containers. I know, it's still in Milestone version.

Comment: Which version of Tomcat? Looks like one that doesn't support proper websockets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a bad WAR file to me (the embedded tomcat jars shoudln't be in `WEB-INF/lib` at all). All you should need is to mark the tomcat embedded jars as `scope=provided` in the build configuration. The [GS guide for converting JAR to WAR](https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/) is a good reference for standard configuration options, and there are several samples in the Spring Boot codebase.

If your app is not using the web socket features of tomcat it should still work with older versions (so please feel free to raise an issue in [github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot)). The easiest fix for you is to simply upgrade tomcat (7.0.47 should work).

Answer (score 7):

Modify your `pom.xml` with the following lines:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

This will ensure that the embeded tomcat-server isnt provided to your web-app when you deploy to a server.

Answer (score 0):

Use providedRuntime in Gradle to move the tomcat jars to WEB-INF/lib-provided folder as recommended in Gradle documentation

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
}
```